# not sure what's the problem with this "regex" in the "grep" shell command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

This was my attempt:

```
grep -i 'th[\D]\{1,\}'
```

I'm on hackerRank. I have this file that is delivered to my stdin.

I need as a result lines that contains :

```
the
that
then
those
```

Comment: There are many different regex dialects and you are using the wrong one. `grep` uses "Posix Basic RegEx (BRE)" and not "Perl Compatible RegEx (PCRE)" that you appear to be using

Comment: With BRE, you can write `[\D]` as `[^[:digit:]]` for "non-digit"

Comment: Is you're using GNU grep, you can use the `-P` option to use PCRE.

Comment: `grep -i 'th[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}' file`

Comment: How did you came up with that regex? It is very unusual for the goal you described. Wouldn't `the\|that\|then\|those` be the obvious way to go?

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog: See [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) for valid basic regex syntax. You will see that there is no `\D` available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a POSIX BRE pattern, when you use a "shorthand character class" like `\s`, `\w`, even in GNU `grep`, these escape sequences are treated as separate chars, a backslash and a letter. `[\D]\{1,\}` matches one or more `D` letters or `\` chars.

You need to match exactly the words you are told to:

```sh
grep -i -E '\<(the|that|then|those)\>'
```

Here,

- `-i` - enables case insensitive matching
- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `\<` - open word boundary
- `(the|that|then|those)` - s capturing group matching any of the word in between `|` (OR) alternation operators
- `\>` - close word boundary.

Comment: the grep command use POSIX BRE by default, and  curly brackets {} are supported by ERE not BRE, doesn't that mean that you should add -E option to use ERE instead ?

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog If we add `-E`, it will look like `grep -i -oE '\<th[[:alpha:]]+' file`

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog did it finally work for you?

Comment: i tried the solution on a file in my shell prompt, also hackerrank website, still it doesn't seem to give any result. If you may, here is the challenge   https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-processing-in-linux-the-grep-command-4/problem?h_r=profile&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: let me know why it doesn't behave as expected

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog I updated with the working pattern.

Comment: why not `grep -i -E '\<th(e|at|en|ose)\>'` or maybe even just `grep -i -E '\<th[a-z]+'`

Comment: @Bohemian It is a hackerrank exercise, and `grep -i -E '\<th[a-z]+'` triggers "Wrong Answer :(" response. `grep -i -E '\<th(e|at|en|ose)\>'` is the same regex as mine, just refactored to be less readable.